# ASP.NET: Wrong Code Displayed in Crash Dump

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, yellow-screen-of-death

So a webapp I've been working on broke, and I made some fixes... it still crashes, but in the YSOD it shows me the old code. I'm running this from the VS 2005 IDE. It won't hit any breakpoints, and it crashes on line 249, which is clearly commented out. I've cleared out my debug/release folders and rebuilt it; restarted IIS (just in case); what would cause this?

```
Could not find file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\map.xml'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\map.xml'.

Source Error: 

Line 248:    //XmlDocument xMap = new XmlDocument();
Line 249:    //xMap.Load(MapPath("map.xml"));
```

Comment: Are you also using the built-in web server for VS, or just IIS?  Sounds like a shadow copy issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code probably did not compile, therefore the metadata in the DLL is for your old code.